# How to display x lines before a record and x lines after a find record when we have two of the same string

Tags: linux, xml, grep

How to display, for example, 10 lines before a found record and 10 lines after a found record when we have two of the same string in one file ? See file example (RECORD in line 10 is our search):

```
<Test1>  </Test1>
<Test2>  </Test2>
<Test3>  </Test3>
<Test4>  </Test4>
<Test5>  </Test5>
<Test6>  </Test6>
<Test7>  </Test7>
<Test8>  </Test8>
<Test9>  </Test9>
<Test10> **RECORD** </Test10>
<Test11>  </Test11>
<Test12>  </Test12>
<Test13>  </Test13>
<Test14>  </Test14>
<Test15> RECORD </Test15>
<Test16>  </Test16>
<Test17>  </Test17>
<Test18>  </Test18>
<Test19>  </Test19>
<Test20>  </Test20>
```

I tried something like this:

```
grep -m 1 -B 10 -A 10 RECORD *
```

but this only works until the next record met (lines from 1 to 14) and I would like to find all the lines I am looking for.

I expect such a result (aims for the result for the first value):

```
<Test1>  </Test1>
<Test2>  </Test2>
<Test3>  </Test3>
<Test4>  </Test4>
<Test5>  </Test5>
<Test6>  </Test6>
<Test7>  </Test7>
<Test8>  </Test8>
<Test9>  </Test9>
<Test10> **RECORD** </Test10>
<Test11>  </Test11>
<Test12>  </Test12>
<Test13>  </Test13>
<Test14>  </Test14>
<Test15> RECORD </Test15>
<Test16>  </Test16>
<Test17>  </Test17>
<Test18>  </Test18>
<Test19>  </Test19>
<Test20>  </Test20>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do add sample of expected output also in  your question. To make it clear from which line onwards you want to print 10 above and 10 after lines? Is it 1st value? OR last value? OR can there be more than 2 same lines in same file?

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code. As per your shown samples I have neglected null values in xml file. Reading the Input_file 2 times here in `awk` program.

```
awk -F"[><]" '
FNR==NR{
  if($3){ arr1[$3]++ }
  arr2[FNR]=$0
  next
}
$3!~/^[[:space:]]++$/ && arr1[$3]>1 && !($3 in arr3){
  for(i=(FNR-10);i<=FNR;i++){
    if(arr2[i]){ print arr2[i] }
  }
  for(i=(FNR+1);i<=(FNR+10);i++){
    print arr2[i]
  }
  arr3[$3]
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** This will look for all those strings who are having more than 1 occurrences in Input_file and it will print 10 above and 10 below lines from 1st occurrence itself as per shown samples but it will do this operation for all eligible/found strings.

Comment: @matrix1395, could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you?